# Calling function without the arguments it was defined with

Tags: python-3.x, function, beautifulsoup

I am working on some examples of BeautifulSoup4 on Python and can't understand the syntax of the following example:

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

def list_with_links(tag):   # takes a tag object
    return tag.name == 'li' and len(tag.find_all('a'))>7  

list_with_a = soup.find_all(list_with_links)
```

My question is- **How** can you call the function list_with_links without any argument passed, and **how** does it return what it returns (a result list of the tags that matched the terms inside the function)?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass only the name of a function (without parentheses and arguments ) you just pass a pointer to that function, you don't execute it. Then you can call this pointer (with parentheses and arguments) and will be executed normally. See an example:

```
def select(f):
    all_data = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66]
    res_data = []
    for data in all_data:
        if f(data):
            res_data.append(data)
    return res_data

def filter(value):
        return True if value%2 == 0 else False

print(select(filter))  # [22, 44, 66]
```

Comment: So in this case- the function got soup as the argument to look at or was it just used to return the conditions and use them if the find_all mothod?

Comment: Through the function `list_with_links()` passed the conditions `tag.name == 'li' and len(tag.find_all('a'))>7` to the `find_all()` method, so will be returned results that match these conditions.